# On Photoshop, how do I export without the effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I have a low poly portrait that I want to export to a JPEG or PNG. The polygons have strokes around them as an effect. In Photoshop I can hide the effects, however when I export it as a JPEG the effects remain. How do I remove the effects/strokes when exporting? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Do one of the following:

1. In the Layers panel, drag the Effects bar to the Delete icon .
2. Choose Layer > Layer Style > Clear Layer Style.
3. Select the layer, and then click the Clear Style button at the bottom of the Styles panel.

Quick Google search, silly me...

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Good you got it sorted but it's probably best if you google before asking